# Hiding an Excel worksheet with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office

I have an Excel spreadsheet with three sheets. One of the sheets contains formulas for one of the other sheets.

Is there a programmatic way to hide the sheet which contains these formulas?

Answer (score 70):

To hide from the UI, use Format > Sheet > Hide

To hide programatically, use the `Visible` property of the `Worksheet` object. If you do it programatically, you can set the sheet as "very hidden", which means it cannot be unhidden through the UI.

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Name").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden 
' or xlSheetHidden or xlSheetVisible
```

You can also set the Visible property through the properties pane for the worksheet in the VBA IDE (<kbd>ALT+F11</kbd>).

Comment: @MárioMeyrelles Not on a computer with Excel so I can't try out myself - what is **very** hidden?!

Comment: it means you can't unhide it from the ribbon (format > hide & unhide > unhide sheet). You can only unhide it via VBA.

Answer (score 22):

You can do this programmatically using a VBA macro. You can make the sheet *hidden* or *very hidden*:

```
Sub HideSheet()

    Dim sheet As Worksheet

    Set sheet = ActiveSheet

    ' this hides the sheet but users will be able 
    ' to unhide it using the Excel UI
    sheet.Visible = xlSheetHidden

    ' this hides the sheet so that it can only be made visible using VBA
    sheet.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden

End Sub
```

Answer (score 19):

Just wanted to add a little more detail to the answers given.  You can also use

```
sheet.Visible = False
```

to hide and

```
sheet.Visible = True
```

to unhide.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197786.aspx)

Comment: Is this a `hidden` or `very hidden` way?

Comment: Well, combining https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/xlsheetvisibility-enumeration-excel and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/boolean-data-type, it looks like `True` and `xlSheetVisible` are both -1, and `False` and `xlSheetHidden` are 0. This implies that `sheet.Visible = False` is equivalent to `sheet.Visible = xlSheetHidden`.

Answer (score 6):

This can be done in a single line, as long as the worksheet is active:

```
ActiveSheet.Visible = xlSheetHidden
```

However, you may not want to do this, especially if you use any "select" operations or you use any more ActiveSheet operations.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to answer your question, as there are various methods - here I’ll talk about the code that is widely used.

So, for hiding the sheet:

```
Sub try()
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Visible = xlSheetHidden
End Sub
```

There are other methods also if you want to learn all Methods [Click here](http://excelvbaautomation.com/hide-unhide-worksheet/)