# Excel VBA hide sheets with names in array

Tags: vba, excel

I want to hide all tabs whose names are `"ABC", "DEF", "GHI"`

This is my code:

```
Sub hideSheets()
Dim ws As Worksheet
invisible = Array("ABC", "DEF", "GHI")

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each nome In invisible
        If ws.Name = nome Then
            ws.Visible = False
        Else
            ws.Visible = True
        End If
    Next nome

Next ws

End Sub
```

Which isn't hiding any sheet.

Comment: This has been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/853270/hiding-an-excel-sheet).  You need to use: xlSheetVeryHidden, xlSheetHidden or xlSheetVisible after the `=` instead of true or false.

Comment: @ScottCraner That question's answers do not address the array component in the title of the question. In addition your comment, while not wrong, is misleading. `xlSheetHidden = 0`, which is exactly equivalent to False ,   `xlSheetVisible = -1` which is exactly equivalent to True. So those two visible states can and often are achieved by using the simple Boolean values. `xlSheetVeryHidden = 2` which can be set either with the constant or the literal or an expression. In any case, nothing from that other question addresses this question.

Comment: @ExcelHero As always, I bow to your knowledge.

Comment: @ScottCraner :) Well no need for that, but the more knowledge we share the better everyone becomes!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To hide the sheets in your `invisible` array, it is as simple as this:

```
Sheets(invisible).Visible = False
```

Note: this works well for hiding. To make the sheets visible again, you must set each sheet visible one by one; you cannot use the array in one line like you can for hiding.

Comment: LOL! this is really simple!

Comment: Any other simple way of unhiding anything that isn't in that array?

Comment: Nope. Unhiding requires doing one sheet at a time.

Comment: Ok, I've unhidden all the sheets one by one and then hidden the ones in the array. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks @NunoNogueira.

Answer (score 1):

Take out the `else`. It hides it but on the next loop, it unhides again.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
invisible = Array("ABC", "DEF", "GHI")

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.WorkSheets

    For Each nome In invisible
        If ws.name = nome Then
            ws.Visible = False
        End If
    Next nome

Next ws
```