# What does "xlSheetHidden" represent? Is it a function?

Tags: vba, excel

I encountered the following code:

```
Sub HideSheets()
    Dim Sht As Worksheet
    For Each Sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Sht.Name <> ActiveSheet.Name Then
            Sht.Visible = xlSheetHidden
        End If
    Next Sht
End Sub
```

What it does is to use a loop to hide all worksheets in the active workbook, except the active sheet. What is xlSheetHidden and why is it not defined?

Comment: Please try searching next time.  This was one of the top hits on a Google search for "xlSheetHidden": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/853270/hiding-an-excel-sheet.  Also: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlsheetvisibility.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Its an *enumeration*.  Normally something like this would be *True* or *False*, but here we have three possibilities, including `xlSheetVeryHidden`