# Close another workbook upon closing the workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code that opens another *workbook (source.xlsx)* when I open (triggers on *Workbook_Open* event) a template *workbook (template.xlsm)*.

The code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
 Application.Screenupdating= False
 Set w = workbooks
 w.open filename:="link", Updatelinks:=true , readonly:=true
 activewindow.visible=false
 thisworkbook.activate
 application.screenupdating=True
end sub
```

However, I want the source workbook to just run on background upon opening and close it when I close the template file.

```
Private sub workbook_aftersave()
 Workbook("source.xlsx").Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: You can try what was done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41058450/2685412).

Comment: You might want to clarify the question slightly - you have had both a comment and an answer about *hiding* the workbook, which your code should already do, instead of about *closing* it which is where I think your error actually is - perhaps you could add a paragraph on "This is what I expect/want, this is what I actually get"?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the `Workbooks` collection (`Workbooks("source.xlsx")`), rather than a `Workbook` object (`Workbook("source.xlsx")`, which will throw an error).  Also, rather than trying to close it on the `Workbook_AfterSave` event, you could try using the `Workbook_BeforeClose` event:

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    On Error Resume Next 'In case the Workbook is already closed
    Workbooks("source.xlsx").Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

**{EDIT}** *And, because I can, here's a tidier version of your `Workbook_Open` code too:*

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim wsSource As Workbook
    Set wsSource = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="SomeDirectory\source.xlsx", UpdateLinks:=True, ReadOnly:=True) 'Change the filename to where your "source.xlsx" is stored
    DoEvents 'Wait for it to finish opening
    wsSource.Windows(1).Visible = False
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using

```
Application.Visible = False
```

Place this in your Workbook_Open code on the workbook you want to hide, and then use True to bring it back to close.