# Unhide worksheet

Tags: vba, visible

I am creating a spreadsheet to record unit finances.  The spreadsheet I am using as a template/demo for mine has a hidden worksheet that I'm trying to view.

I have googled, and tried what has been suggested, including VBA.

What can I do to see this worksheet?  (I would upload the file, but I don't know how)

Comment: "I have tried what has been suggest" - give exact examples

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hiding an Excel worksheet with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853270/hiding-an-excel-worksheet-with-vba)

Answer (score 0):

For a specific sheet:

```
Worksheets("MySheet").Visible = xlSheetVisible
```

Make all sheets in the workbook visible:

```
Sub MakeAllSheetsVisible()
    Dim sht As Worksheet

    For Each sht In Worksheets
        If Not sht.Visible Then
            sht.Visible = xlSheetVisible
        End If
    Next sht
End Sub
```

Comment: I've tried this, but I get the error 'Compile error: Invalid outside procedure'

Comment: Which code snippet are you running and where? You’ve placed inside a Sub...End Sub right?

Comment: Yes.  I copied all of the above as it says there.  I changed the "MySheet" to "Sheet5"

Comment: Just to be clear, the code snippets are separate i.e. you use one or the other. If you used the first one make sure you wrap it within Sub...End Sub

Comment: I'm getting:  "Runtime Error 1004:  Method 'Visible' of object '_Worksheet' failed.  When I go to debug, the line 'she.Visible - xlSheetVisible' is highlighted

Comment: Is the `sht` you get the error on password protected?

Comment: I have removed the password, but it still won't work

Comment: In which case I am stuck for what to do next...I can't think what else this could be. Works on my machine perfectly well.